# how to set CSV delimiter in OSX Lion?

Tags: ms-office

I live in Indonesia and we use the dd/mm/yyyy date format as opposed to America's mm/dd/yyyy. Questions:

1. I changed my Language settings to Indonesia region so that this date format would be recognized as a date in Excel. It worked, but somehow Excel won't recognize a comma as a delimiter for CSVs anymore. How shall I solve this?
2. Is there a way to get Excel to recognize this date format without changing the Language settings?

Thanks

Comment: What version of excel do you have?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2011, open a workbook,

Click on Format > Style and you get this window

[image]

In here click format again and you get this window

[image]

Pick the Date format you want,
or make a custom format in your case dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: No sorry that's not correct. That's just to change the format of the Date that's in the cell, provided that Excel RECOGNIZES the string as Date. The problem is using United States standard Excel will look for month-date-year, but where I am from we use date-month-year.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you show an example!

Comment: OK sure. Example: 31/01/2013, and try to set that as a Date.

Comment: I did, and it works as 31/01/2013 than to check it i used -1 day formula, so it comes up with correct answer of 30/01/2013. Or -33 days = 29/12/2012

Comment: I left it on US and added custom date format as dd/mm/yyyy in excel, and I also tried with Setting the excel on Indonesia-Indonesian.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It didn't work for me. It didn't work for me unfortunately. I set A1=31/01/2013 and B1=A1-1 and got #VALUE! However if I set A1=01/31/2013 then I get 01/30/2013 correct. How do you "setting the excel on Indonesian-Indonesian"?